# Нет изменений в ветке

Tags: git, github

В репозитории есть две ветки: master и date. Сделав некоторые изменения в date, слил ее с master. После этого добавил некоторые изменения в ветку master. И теперь, когда я снова хочу работать с веткой date, в ней нет последних изменений ветки master. Подскажите, что нужно сделать?(делать merge date с master еще раз?)

Comment: Перед слиянием вы только в `date` добавляли коммиты или в `master` тоже?

Comment: @NickVolynkin перед слиянием я работал только date и коммитил только в date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо либо сделать `rebase` втеки `date` на ветку `master`, а потом `force push` в ветку `date`, либо сделать мёрж ветки `master` в ветку `date` и просто сделать `push`.

По моему мнению `rebase` предпочтительнее для второстепенных веток, а вот когда нужно слить изменения в мастер, тогда необходимо делать `merge`.

Только в этом случае ветка `date` получит обновления ветки `master`.

Подробнее про отличия `rebase` от `merge` [здесь](https://tyvik.ru/blog/49)

Comment: "force push" тут совершенно не нужен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin без `force push` могут появиться дубликаты коммитов

Comment: Откуда? Там дважды fast-forward merge будет.

Comment: При условии, что в мастер не коммитили, а если коммитили, то мы 2 раза не делали rebase с него

Answer (score 1):

Если до слияния вы добавляли изменения только в `date`, то история была примерно такая (буквами обозначены коммиты):

```
A --- B (master)
       \
        C --- D (date)
```

Проверить историю можно командой `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`. Там будет вертикальный граф (дерево), но я рисую горизонтальный, потому что так удобнее.

По умолчанию, если `master` является прямым предком ветки `date` (как бы «полностью содержится в ней»), при мерже происходит «перемотка» (fast-forward): указатель `master` просто перемещается на `date`. Результат такой:

```
git checkout master
git merge date

A --- B --- C --- D (master, date)
```

Потом вы сделали ещё коммит в `master`:

```
git commit

A --- B --- C --- D (date)
                   \
                    E (master)
```

Теперь, чтобы обновить `date` до состояния `master`, можно:

- Замержить (слить) `master` в `date`:

  ```
  git checkout date
  git merge master
  ```
- Переставить `date` на `master`.

  ```
  git checkout date
  git reset --hard master
  ```

Comment: спасибо, а можно ли как то удалить промежуточный коммит, например C  с сохранением коммита D? Нужно сделать откат до этого коммита, а потом git --hard reset?

Comment: @takecaretakecaretakecare не путайте, не `--hard reset`, а `reset --hard`. Тут `--reset` – это параметр команды `reset`. И эта команда делает историю текущей ветки точно (абсолютно) такой же, как и целевой.

Comment: @takecaretakecaretakecare дальше, что вы понимаете под удалением? Вы хотите отменить изменения из этого коммита или просто слить его с предыдущим или последующим?

Comment: Отменить изменения из коммита C. Я обнаружил ошибку в коде и хотел бы убрать эти изменения, но в коммите D все верно, и я хочу, чтобы изменения из него остались